# Remove duplicate form inputs while serializing and submitting two or more forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have two forms holding the common action with inputs with same names. First my requirement is to submit the individual forms which i can do easily. Then i need to submit both the forms at a time by serializing and sending through ajax. Here the problem is, as both the forms contains inputs with same names duplicate values are going through post. How can i prevent it?

Ex:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
var dataString=$('#form1, #form2').serialize();
$.ajax({
            url: "someOther.jsp",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataString,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
      });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="some.jsp" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="hidden"  name="hField1" value="value1">
<input type="hidden"  name="hField2" value="value2">
<input type="text" id="field11" name="field11">
<input type="text" id="field21" name="field21">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<form action="some.jsp" method="post" id="form2">
<input type="hidden"  name="hField1" value="value1">
<input type="hidden"  name="hField2" value="value2">
<input type="text" id="field12" name="field12">
<input type="text" id="field22" name="field22">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Do they **have** to be all named the same? Simple solution - change the names in the second form. Secondly, you could use some type of counter on the server side to detect the second form but you'd need to show your server side to help there..

Comment: The hidden fields are unique fields which go into a query on the server side. So they must be with same name.

Comment: Having duplicate ids is invalid I'm only front-end but from what I see if your server requires invalid HTML, then you should reassess how it functions.

Comment: @zer00ne I agree that having duplicate IDs is invalid but for names there is no such condition and moreover there is no use of IDs in my requirement. Please let me know if there is a simplest way other than using array names.

Comment: @AdityaRao I agree with dupe names all the way, it's valid and orthodox.  But you have `#hField1` and `#hField2` duplicated. As it stands, only the first 2 sets would be visible to browser and the 2nd set would be ignored if you try to find them by #id. I guess my habit is to do things correct (to the best of my knowledge) just in case in the future it doesn't bite me in the @ss.

Comment: @zer00ne  thnx for ur suggestion. I removed those IDs as they are of no use in my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
$(".neglect").remove();
var dataString=$('#form1, #form2').serialize();
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "someOther.jsp",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataString,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
      });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="some.jsp" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="hField1" value="value1">
<input type="hidden" name="hField2" value="value2">
<input type="text" id="field11" name="field11">
<input type="text" id="field21" name="field21">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<form action="some.jsp" method="post" id="form2">
<input type="hidden" class="neglect" name="hField1" value="value1">
<input type="hidden" class="neglect" name="hField2" value="value2">
<input type="text" id="field12" name="field12">
<input type="text" id="field22" name="field22">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to make those arrays instead of single values, like this:

```
<form action="some.jsp" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" id="hField1" name="hField1[]" value="value1">
<input type="hidden" id="hField2" name="hField2[]" value="value2">
<input type="text" id="field11" name="field11[]">
<input type="text" id="field21" name="field21[]">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<form action="some.jsp" method="post" id="form2">
<input type="hidden" id="hField1" name="hField1[]" value="value1">
<input type="hidden" id="hField2" name="hField2[]" value="value2">
<input type="text" id="field12" name="field12[]">
<input type="text" id="field22" name="field22[]">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send both forms data in 2 different variables.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn").on("click",function(){
      var form1=$('#form1').serialize();
      var form2=$('#form2').serialize();
       $.ajax({
        url: "someOther.jsp",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {form1:form1,form2:form2},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
  });
 });
});
```

And on the other side get both form data differently.